# Permission to Send data

Tags: android, permissions

Is there a permission to send data to the server ? 
Because my data sent to the server when I use java project but when the code written in android project the data can not be uploaded.
Thanks...

Comment: please Ask properly with code & issue..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have **Internet permission** in **Manifest file**? If not, add this

```
<uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

into manifest file.

Comment: Can you please post logcat messages?